# JSON error parsing a dictionary from a ruby on rails server in objective c app

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails

I have a small Ruby on Rails server that replies to get requests by a objective-c client. Since I need to accumulate data from different tables I decided to put it in a dictionary (hash in rails) and then send it as a JSON and on the client I use the iOS 5 JSON framework to reconstruct the dictionary. Here are simpler parts of my code:

```
format.json { render :json => {:message_type => 'getBaseOpReply',
       :base_longitude => @operator.base_longitude,             
       :base_latitude => @operator.base_latitude} }
```

and on the client I use the connection data delegate where in `connection:didReceiveData` I accumulate the data in `responseData` and in `connectionDidFinishLoading` I do:

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
```

I get the following error:
`ErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 ... JSON text did not start with array or object` etc.

I tried with all the different options for the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` and I get the same error except when I use the `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`. Then it is a bit different saying `Invalid value` around character 0.

I assume my server is not properly constructing the dictionary but please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you test the output of the server? Is the output correct?

Comment: Figured it out - I did not denote my methods in the routes.rb file since their names were not matching the REST specification